# How do you use P5 loadImage() with React props from FileReader?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, p5.js

I am trying to change an image based on input from a FileReader API in a different React component and passing the image name in as props.

--For some reason, this is totally not working. I wonder if I'm interpolating the file name correctly where the data URL goes.

Have tried the P5 createFileReader, which also didn't work (forgot why), and decided not to use it because the button was too ugly.

Any help would be appreciated!

This is the P5 environment:

```
import React from 'react'; 
import Sketch from 'react-p5';
import FileInput from '../FileInput'; 

let cvs; 
let img; 
let pg; 



export default function P5Lasso(){
const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
const [load, setLoaded] = React.useState(false);
 

function setup(p5, canvasParentRef) {
    cvs = p5.createCanvas(600, 600).parent(canvasParentRef);
    p5.loadImage(`${image}`, img => {image(img, 0, 0); console.log('load')});
    if (img !== null) {
        setLoaded(true); 
    } else { 
        return( console.log('load error')); }
    }

function draw(p5) {

stuff
        
    }


return (
    <div>
    <FileInput selectImage={(img) => setImage(img)} />
    {load && <div>
    <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} mouseReleased={mouseReleased}/> 
    </div>
    }
    </div>
    ); 
    }
```

This is the File Reader:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';

export default function FileInput(props) { 

const [src, setSrc]= useState(null); 
const fileInput = useRef(null);
  
const handleImageSelection = (event) => {
    props.selectImage(event.target.files[0].name); 
    console.log(event.target.files[0].name);

    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function (e) {
    setSrc(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
};

const openFileInput = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };

return (
  <div
      className="image-input"
      onClick={openFileInput}
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        height: "400px",
        border: "2px solid",
        borderRadius: "5px",
        color: "black",
  
      }}
    
    >
      <img
        style={{ height: "100%" }}
        className="loaded-image"
        src={src}
        alt=""
      />

      <label>
        <input
          ref={fileInput}
          style={{ display: "none" }}
          type="file"
          accept="image/*"
          onChange={handleImageSelection}
        />
      </label>
    </div>
 ); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `props.selectImage` in `FileReader` component with the result from reading the file as data URI.

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function FileInput(props) {
  const [src, setSrc] = useState(null);
  const fileInput = useRef(null);

  const handleImageSelection = event => {
    let file = event.target.files[0];
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
      setSrc(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (src) {
      props.selectImage(src);
    }
  }, [src]);

  const openFileInput = () => {
    fileInput.current.click();
  };
//...
```

Then, use that in Sketch component to render the sketch if there is an image.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import Sketch from 'react-p5';
import FileInput from './FileInput';

let cvs;
let img;
let pg;


export default function P5Lasso() {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState(null);
  function setup(p5, canvasParentRef) {
    cvs = p5.createCanvas(600, 600).parent(canvasParentRef);
    p5.loadImage(image, img => {
      p5.image(img, 0, 0);
    });
  }

  function draw(p5) {
  }

  function mouseReleased() {}

  return (
    <div>
      <FileInput selectImage={setImage} />
      {image && (
        <div>
          <Sketch setup={setup} draw={draw} mouseReleased={mouseReleased}/>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Check it out on [StackBlitz](https://react-oo8nu4.stackblitz.io/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer Oluwafemi! I‘m not able to upvote yet because I’m new here.

Comment: @Jie-LiangLin You can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark next to it, though.

Comment: I didn't have permission previously. Thanks again!